# PHPMYADMIN. Очень долго открывается страница добавления/изменения строки таблицы

Tags: phpmyadmin

Здравствуйте.

Очень долго открывается в PHPMYADMIN страница добавления/изменения строки в структуре таблицы.

Использую OpenServer. На компьютере процессор i7. К примеру открытие для просмотра таблицы товаров с 10 тыс. записей и выводом по 250 записей на странице занимает до 7 сек.(сам запрос занял 0.0139 сек.), а открыть страницу чтобы добавить/изменить поле этой таблицы - до 25 сек.

Подскажите, какие параметры и где нужно настроить?

Comment: Никогда не пользуйтесь этой гадостью - openserver (и подобными прожектами всё в одном)

Comment: @Sergey - аргументируйте. Если используется как основная система windows, запускать виртуальную машину с линуксом для мелких правок как-то не очень удобно...

Comment: Ваш вопрос - вот аргумент.

Comment: Не могу сказать на счет phpmyadmin, но просто рекомендовал бы использовать SQLYog или MyWorkBench или подобную программу для работы с БД, нежели браузерный админ....... одно дело силами браузера работать, другое - программой. небо и земля................. а `openserver` пользуйтесь - классная вещь (только лучше не full pack а полегче). Не слушайте **Sergey**. Он "тру" джавист и не понимает в этом ничего

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо за ваш ответ. В комплекте OpenServere есть программа HeidiSQL, я часто ею пользуюсь, работать с ним действительно быстрее чем с phpmyadmin. Но пару раз он подводил - при импорте больших  файлов. с phpmyadmin более удачно и быстрее получалось.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да я тут по пхп не меньше некоторых подсказывать. Жавист тут совершенно не причём. Чем ставить левые сборки, собранные непонятно кем, лучше взять с первоисточников и поставить штатным способом. Да многое там просто мусор. Сами же пишите лучше MyWorkbench. А ещё лучше MS SQL сервер со студией. Нафига вы эту гадость тягаете?

Comment: @Sergey Так я не говорю что MyWorkbench лучше openserver. Говорю, что лучше силами системы играть с БД нежели браузера,где и работает phpmyadmin. Openserver тут вообще не причем. Разраб operservera не является разрабом пхпадмина и не ответственнен за его глючесть.......Но если откинуть админку в нем достаточно много разных модулей и инструментов облегчающих жизнь... особенно если нужно частенько менять версии модулей в зависимости от задачи. И основной десяток инструментов, входящих в состав вполне справляется на отлично всегда. А вы просто шаблонный хейтер, что пхп, что его инструментов